# Stale element exception under shadow dom

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, staleelementreferenceexception, stalestateexception

I'm facing a problem with a stale element under the shadow DOM, scenario below:

1. hover to the video and the dock is shown and vice versa
2. HTML Dom changes from not hovering to hovering and vice versa:

*The below html is for not hovering.*

```
<div class="base overlay hidden" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:139px;height:387px;width:516px;"><div class="downloads"><div class="hide-btn" id="hide-widget">
</div>

<ul class="main main-panel">
<li class="panel">
    <span class="select" id="preferred-select" data-selected-value="High">Preferred quality: High</span>
    <a class="download-btn" id="download-main" title="DOWNLOAD">
        <span>DOWNLOAD</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="message-panel">
    <a class="message" id="showhide-all"></a>
</li>
</ul>

<!-- Progress box for content script -->
<div class="tooltip-box">
    <div class="play-and-progress-box" hidden="">
        <div class="progress-box">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="percent"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="play-now-btn" id="play-now">
            <span class="play-now-play-icon">▶</span> Play now
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip bleft">
        Click to <b>Play now</b> to watch downloading video now!
        <form action="" class="not-show">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="abc" id="play-now-not-show-check">
            <label for="play-now-not-show-check">Do not show again</label>
        </form>
        <span class="closebtn" id="close-play-now-tooltip">+</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="downloads"></div>

<div class="mobile-btn">
    <div id="open-mobile">
        <div class="tooltip">Mobile</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="open-pip" class="pip-btn">
    <div class="tooltip">Pin</div>
</div>

<div id="switch-light" class="light-btn">
    <div class="tooltip">Lights off</div>
</div>

<div id="skipping_ads" class="skipping-ads-btn" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;);">
    <div class="tooltip">Disable Auto skip ads</div>
</div>

<div class="skipping-ads-tooltip">
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-wand-block">
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-wand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-block">
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-title">Auto skip ads</div>
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-content">Cốc Cốc can skip video ads automatically for you. Do you want to enable it now?</div>
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-notice">This is not an ad blocker, it just automates the process of clicking on the "Skip Ad" button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn">
        <div id="skipping-ads-btn-cancel" class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn-cancel">
            Cancel
        </div>
        <div id="skipping-ads-btn-ok" class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn-ok">
            Yes, enable
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-box hidden">
    <div class="mobile-content-box">
        <div class="mobile-content-column-box">
            <div class="mobile-content-column">
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-header first">
                    <span class="mobile-instruction-text">
                        <span class="step-number">1</span>
                        Open Cốc Cốc Mobile
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-instructions">
                    <img src="" alt="Instruction" class="instruction-image">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="mobile-content-column">
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-header second">
                    <span class="mobile-instruction-text">
                        <span class="step-number">2</span>
                        Scan QR code
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-switch-box">
                    <div class="switch">

                        <div class="switch-field">
                            <input type="radio" id="switch-video" name="send-type" value="video" checked="">
                            <label for="switch-video">Video</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="switch-audio" name="send-type" value="audio">
                            <label for="switch-audio">Audio</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-qrcode">
                    <div class="qrcode loading"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-content mobile-footer">
            <span class="footer-text"> Don't have Cốc Cốc Browser on mobile? </span>
            <div class="download-web-stores">
                <div class="stores google-play" id="google-play">
                </div>
                <div class="stores app-store" id="app-store">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

*After hovered, the change is:*

```
<div class="base overlay" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:139px;height:387px;width:516px;"><div class="downloads"><div class="hide-btn" id="hide-widget">
</div>

<ul class="main main-panel">
<li class="panel">
    <span class="select" id="preferred-select" data-selected-value="High">Preferred quality: High</span>
    <a class="download-btn" id="download-main" title="DOWNLOAD">
        <span>DOWNLOAD</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="message-panel">
    <a class="message" id="showhide-all"></a>
</li>
</ul>

<!-- Progress box for content script -->
<div class="tooltip-box">
    <div class="play-and-progress-box" hidden="">
        <div class="progress-box">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="percent"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="play-now-btn" id="play-now">
            <span class="play-now-play-icon">▶</span> Play now
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip bleft">
        Click to <b>Play now</b> to watch downloading video now!
        <form action="" class="not-show">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="abc" id="play-now-not-show-check">
            <label for="play-now-not-show-check">Do not show again</label>
        </form>
        <span class="closebtn" id="close-play-now-tooltip">+</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="downloads"></div>

<div class="mobile-btn">
    <div id="open-mobile">
        <div class="tooltip">Mobile</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="open-pip" class="pip-btn">
    <div class="tooltip">Pin</div>
</div>

<div id="switch-light" class="light-btn">
    <div class="tooltip">Lights off</div>
</div>

<div id="skipping_ads" class="skipping-ads-btn" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;);">
    <div class="tooltip">Disable Auto skip ads</div>
</div>

<div class="skipping-ads-tooltip">
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-wand-block">
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-wand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-block">
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-title">Auto skip ads</div>
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-content">Cốc Cốc can skip video ads automatically for you. Do you want to enable it now?</div>
        <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-notice">This is not an ad blocker, it just automates the process of clicking on the "Skip Ad" button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn">
        <div id="skipping-ads-btn-cancel" class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn-cancel">
            Cancel
        </div>
        <div id="skipping-ads-btn-ok" class="skipping-ads-tooltip-btn-ok">
            Yes, enable
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-box hidden">
    <div class="mobile-content-box">
        <div class="mobile-content-column-box">
            <div class="mobile-content-column">
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-header first">
                    <span class="mobile-instruction-text">
                        <span class="step-number">1</span>
                        Open Cốc Cốc Mobile
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-instructions">
                    <img src="" alt="Instruction" class="instruction-image">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="mobile-content-column">
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-header second">
                    <span class="mobile-instruction-text">
                        <span class="step-number">2</span>
                        Scan QR code
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-switch-box">
                    <div class="switch">

                        <div class="switch-field">
                            <input type="radio" id="switch-video" name="send-type" value="video" checked="">
                            <label for="switch-video">Video</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="switch-audio" name="send-type" value="audio">
                            <label for="switch-audio">Audio</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-content mobile-qrcode">
                    <div class="qrcode loading"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-content mobile-footer">
            <span class="footer-text"> Don't have Cốc Cốc Browser on mobile? </span>
            <div class="download-web-stores">
                <div class="stores google-play" id="google-play">
                </div>
                <div class="stores app-store" id="app-store">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

3. The code to get the Element after mouse hover as below:

```
public static WebElement getElementFromShadow(String jsPath) {
WebElement element = null
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
JavascriptExecutor jse = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)

int attempts = 0;
while (attempts < 5) {
try {
element = ((jse.executeScript('return ' + jsPath)) as WebElement)
if (element != null) {
break;
}
else {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(((jse.executeScript('return ' + jsPath)) as WebElement)))
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace()
}
attempts++
Thread.sleep(2000)
}

return element
}
```

but when run it, I got org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

PS: the above code works fine with the normal shadow element(No DOM is changed).

Could anyone know any idea/solution to solve the issue, thank you in advance!

Comment: when you hover mouse  html class `class="base overlay hidden" ` changes to `class="base overlay`

Comment: yes, all of the others no changed, I've compared

Comment: Catch the exception org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException and again search for the element what you are referring and perform the actions.